# Sorting a column of values based on index location

Tags: r, csv, sorting

I am currently working with a large amount of data. For testing purposes I am using a smaller batch, but the main point of concern is the sorting of all the data based off of values in one particular column. I have posted a picture below that shows a small portion of my unsorted data. I want to sort the values in row 2 in ascending order along with all other data in those corresponding columns. In other words I don't want to just order row 2, I want to order row 2 and shift all other data with those re-ordered values.

Currently what I do is read in that csv to a data frame (`tmpDF`).

1. After that I transpose the data using `tmpDF <- t(tmpDF)`
2. Now I take that data and order the second column into ascending order (or at least that is what i think I am doing. ) `tmpDF<- tmpDF[order(tmpDF[,1]),]`
3. Re transpose the data to get it back how it was originally, but sorted. Result is shown in picture below "Ordered data result" Keep in mind that the data shown between the unsorted and sorted are different numbers due to my not posting my entire data set.

[image: Example of unsorted values]

[image: Ordered data result]

***I have a few questions about this.***

**1) Am I going about this the correct way?** I am not a very experienced programmer, just trying to teach myself R to help out my research efforts.

**2) Why are the values such as "102" being represented as "1.01E+02" in my final sorted csv file? I don't believe I am changing type and in the original file they were represented as "102"**

**3) Why does the value 116 gets ordered before "1.01E+02"?**

Comment: Please show an example with `dput` instead of images

Comment: The R programming language uses 1-based arrays, not 0-based, so your `order(tmpDF[,1])` is generating the order of the first column, not the second. For your questions: (Q1) unknown as a whole, but that's a reasonable way to sort; (Q2) see [`?options`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/options.html), specifically about `'digits'` and `'scipen'`; (Q3) likely related to you sorting on the first column, not the second as you intended.

Comment: akrun I did not use dput due to the large output it has, it does not even display all the values in console to paste here. Do you have a better suggestion? I feel the images show what I am asking about just fine.  r2evans, as far as I am concerned my operation is organizing the column I want. If I change that number to 2 it organizes the 3rd column in the output and not the second. I feel that something else is happening here.